# What was novel about the Atari ST? Did it introduce any innovations?

Tags: history, atari-st

Recalling the rise of 16bit era, an era that in my memories was defined mainly by Motorola 68k cpu computers: The Mac, brought the GUI interface. The A bomb, the Amiga, with its custom chips-coprocessors, colourful graphics, stereo sound, pre-emptive multitasking OS and probably other stuff which I forget. And also Atari ST. Well, it had midi ports embedded, making it successful among musicians. I also remember its crisp 70Hz 640x400 monochrome monitor, very easy on the eyes, paired with a nice, legible 8x16 font. But did it bring any novelty, like the aforementioned two (Amiga, Mac)?

PS: I also remember IBM PC with its 8/16bit 8088 cpu as a lousy machine with only one nice feature: Its expansion slots!

Comment: I'm an Amiga/m68k guy and even I would not say something like "The 16-bit era was defined mainly by computers based around the Motorola 680000 CPU". Intel had 16-bit stuff for ages by this point though nothing that would impress many Amiga/ST guys before the 486 era. Then again in the day all my Amiga friends thought of the m68k as 32-bit and didn't think of upgrading to an 020 the same way as upgrading from a Speccy or C64 to an Amiga or ST.

Comment: "The 16-bit era was defined mainly by computers based around the Motorola 68k CPU" - yeah, sure, if you completely ignore all the IBM PC's and clones (which were 16-bit systems), which outsold those 68k-based systems by factors of a few tens of thousands (guesstimated). Pay no attention to that elephant in the corner - it is of no consequence whatsoever!!!

Comment: when it came out, the press called it the Jackintosh (Jack Tramiel - Macintosh), essentially the features of the Mac at a much lower price. The ads were all about pricing as well. The Amstrad computer, popular in Europe, also made its whole marketing based on price and it worked at the time.

Comment: Regarding platforms defining 16bit era (according to me of course!): Probably in North America things were different, but in Europe (I started by recalling my memories) PCs in the 80's were expensive and didn't appeal to home users. The first 16bit computers that massively entered homes were Amigas & Ataris - Macs were also expensive. QLs and other models mentioned, were niche players. That's why I consider these models as the one who defined 16bit era, in Europe at least. PCs started to enter homes in the 32bit era, in vast numbers after 386SX cpu was introduced, the cheaper variant of 386.

Comment: @Cody Gray. I'd suggest to notify/discuss with whoever asks if you intend to make so many alterations to a question. Thank you for the title, it's better. For some spelling corrections also. But the question was turned to something else - written by someone else. Even my british spelling of colourful couldn't survive!

Comment: @Krackout Stack Exchange sites are collaboratively edited. We *never* discuss edits; doing so is off-topic. The edits I made were a *significant* improvement to the question in nearly every way, from grammar to clarity and everything in between. I did not remove any important information, nor did I change anything about the nature or the focus of the question. Changing the spelling of "colourful" was, admittedly, a mistake that occurred because I retyped it the way I would normally spell it without thinking. Otherwise, the edit preserved the entirety of the question's original intent.

Comment: @Cody Gray There was a reason I started using "recalling". These were my memories, so I wanted to stress that all stated before the question (about ST novelties) were my opinion. Starting by "16bit era was defined" made it look like universally accepted. That's what I consider that altered the meaning and reverted the question to its original form - which I intend to keep, as long as it's in my powers.

Comment: I see. Well, that wasn't at all clear to me by how you phrased it. I did not get the impression that you were trying to claim these were only your opinions. Journalists, historians, and other authors will often start sentences much like you did, with "Recalling the era of ...", and they don't mean they're going to talk about their opinions or personal memories. They plan to talk about things that are generally accepted truths. That is how I interpreted your original wording, and what I preserved in my revision. Bolstered by what you went on to say actually *being* generally accepted truths.

Comment: Hmm, probably you are right about it, it was not so clear. I made a slight change, hope it clarifies it.

Comment: @CodyGray “We _never_ discuss edits; doing so is off-topic.” is wrong; in fact, that's one of the primary purposes of comments. See the placeholder text of the comment box.

Comment: In other cases, I've been notified to approve changes. But it was in linux/unix and server sections, where I've got more points; perhaps if you haven't got enough points you are not asked to approve. Don't know the exact stackexchange procedures and limits.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Comments are used to suggest edits. I didn't have a suggestion that I wanted somebody else to do; I made the edit myself. There is no convention on Stack Exchange that you're supposed to suggest or discuss *before* making edits. This would miss the entire point of users having editing privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not required, but you may do so.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As well as being the first colour Mac-like, the Atari ST was absurdly competitive on price, being the first mainstream 68000-based home computer. The Amiga wasn’t relaunched for the home market until 1987*. As a result it is the original home of a wealth of innovative game software — especially in Europe it was often the lead platform for games until the late ‘80s, and even after that it was usually the better platform for 3d titles.

The Atari ST was available with 512kb RAM and the monochrome monitor for $800 in 1985. When it came out later that year, the Amiga had no monitor, 256kb of ram and cost $1,285; you were at very close to $1,600 with a colour monitor.

The Atari ST was the first range to offer 1mb of RAM for less than $1,000, by a safe distance. You could buy one of Atari’s laser printers plus the ST, and DTP software for quite a bit less than Apple’s LaserWriter alone.

Amongst the games software, Eye of the Beholder is commonly cited, as is Another World; nowadays people also tend to mention Alpha Waves, also labelling it the first 3d platformer.

In terms of hardware, I guess the main forward-looking piece is the fully DMA’d implementation of SCSI that drew from a pre-standardisation version of the spec and is therefore usually called ACSI. The Mac wouldn’t gain any SCSI support until the Plus in 1986, and in that implementation it polls a status register then polls a byte, much like how other simple machines read floppy disks; I don’t think Apple ever added DMA drive access to a plain 68000 Mac, though models after the Plus did gain a blocking read so that you don’t have to spin on the status register.

The ST’s DMA controller also drives the floppy disk which was a first for a home computer but I think the IBM PC and clones were already there in terms of machines that you could find in ordinary retail channels.

* this claim has caused some comment controversy; see below. My claim is that the Amiga was originally launched as a professional machine, and an example contemporaneous source is [The LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1985-09-27-fi-18337-story.html):

> ... Commodore--which just began shipping the Amiga--will have to do better than Apple did with its Macintosh or IBM did with the PC in their first years on the market. The Amiga, which starts at $1,300, is intended to compete with more expensive personal computers such as those two.
>
> ...
>
> Because the Amiga, which has won praise from technical reviewers, is a more sophisticated and expensive machine than the more familiar Commodore 64 and the newer Commodore 128, the company isn’t peddling it through K mart and other discount or toy-store chains.
>
> Selling through specialty stores also serves to upgrade the company’s current image as a maker of cheap computers to play games on, which is the part of the computer market hit hardest during the industry’s current weakness.

Comment: So its main novelty, sort of, was its low price. It's an interesting point, although I'm asking for technical or conceptual novelties and innovations, like the ones Amiga and Mac introduced.

Comment: That gets difficult because the target consumer was people graduating from a Commodore 64 or similar, so you possibly run into market delineation arguments, much as you usually do if you attribute anything much to the Macintosh.

Comment: @Tommy What did you mean with, "The Amiga wasn’t relaunched for the home market until 1987."  I bought my Amiga 1000 in 1985.  It was introduced in the USA with TV commercials and full-page (maybe 2-page?) ads in major magazines. Maybe in Europe they waited, but in the USA, they hit the ground running.  Of course their marketing dried up soon thereafter, and even when the Amiga 500 was launched, C= USA didn't push it very much.

Comment: Okay, I’ve added some comments on ACSI, being a DMAd implementation of SCSI that was just slightly pre-standardisation. Most SCSI drives work, I believe, I’m not sure about support for other SCSI devices.

Comment: @RichF I was counting the A1000 as the business-market launch, the A500 as the pivot to the home. My broad strokes understanding of the history being that Commodore intended it as such, being a three-box design that they sold to traditional computer dealers, not to the Walmart/Target-type distribution channels.

Comment: @Tommy I agree there was an initial push for the professional market, but they were pushing games, graphics, and sound from day 1.  I also agree that the A500 was more clearly aimed at the home market, but in my view that was always one of their desired goals.  To be completely honest, I did get my C=128 at Target in 1985 and my Amiga 1000 at a computer store.

Comment: @Tommy: “the first 68000-based home computer”? the TRS-80 Model 16 (1982) and the Sinclair QL (1984) might disagree.

Comment: The ST blitter chip is worth a mention as well.

Comment: @Tommy - I have to disagree with that way of looking at it. At the time "home computers" were largely sold in independent home computer specialty stores, and the Amiga (1000) was in fact sold and marketed as a home computer. The only real exception was the Tandy computers sold in Radio Shacks (and that's only an exception because the RS's were a chain. Radio Shack at the time was still largely positioned as a specialty electronics parts outlet, not a mass-consumer outlet. I bought my A1000 from one such store in November of 1985, and took it home with a copy of Dr. J. and Larry Bird 1-on-1.

Comment: ... One-on-one was also affectionately known as "basket-brick" because they had a coding error on the sprite used for the ball that didn't restrict its allocated memory to the lower 256k (the standard memory space of a stock A1000 before the memory expansion was released), so its data sent to the sprite hardware was a brown pixelated square of random garbage, rather than a ball. The memory expansion was not available early enough in the game's development for the coders to catch that bug.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't know how strongly I can respond to that; I live in America now but I didn't then. In the UK home computers were widely available on the high street from outlets such as WH Smiths, Dixons, Rumbelows, etc, from places like Toys 'R' Us and via generic catalogue shops like Argos. Business computers were the preserve of specialised retailers, though that started to break down when Amstrad started pushing machines like the PCW and PC1512.

Comment: @Tommy - In the US (which again is where these two systems were developed) there was a strong independent computer store culture, selling machines like the Atari 800 line, C64s, and later Amigas and STs, along with the games for them. Teen boys would often hang out there, sometimes getting jobs. To give you an idea, I know of at least one woman here in Tulsa who was into underage boys who took computer store sales jobs for purposes of grooming. She was kind of notorious in the subculture here.

Comment: ... Point being, the Amiga 1000 was in the thick of it here. It was only overseas where they had to make the A500 to be competitive. For some reason the higher price was just a much bigger bugaboo there. I only knew one person in my circle of friends who bought an ST (kind of looked down on. Poor guy had to settle...). Never met anyone with a 500 until more than a decade later. It was kind of a joke at the time.

Comment: @T.E.D.: remember that during the 80s, median income was still a good bit higher in the US than in most of Western Europe, the UK very much included. A US job that would've enabled you to buy an A1000 for your kid without skimping on more necessary expenses usually didn't mean a comparable job in Europe would've done the same.

Comment: @TeaRex - I'm also vaguely remembering something about the dollar being quite strong at the time. Ah. [Here's a link about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_dollar_policy#1980%E2%80%931985).

Comment: @T.E.D.: The same reason why so many 8-bit-era games were published on Tape in the UK - floppy drives were just too expensive for most consumers during the early 80s.

Comment: My understanding is that the built-in MIDI was a definite help in selling to musicians.

Comment: To me the A1000 was only ever an enthusiast's/early adopter's machine. Maybe its price was in the business realm but it had no business software. A friend's brother bought one with some insurance payout money and I bought the first secondhand one I could afford with my low apprentice's wages. I didn't know anyone else who had any Amiga until several years later when it was all A500s and A2000s. I never knew anyone with an ST though it took me months to decide between the A1000 and the ST when they first came out.

Comment: @JimNelson The ST blitter wasn't part of any consumer ST until the STe (1989), and wasn't even ready until after the original Amiga came out with the blitter as a standard part.

Comment: @Tommy You can't connect any SCSI drive to an ACSI bus without an expensive box like ICD Link. Atari's own Megafile range was mostly non-SCSI, with the exception of the SyQuest-based Megafile 44.

Answer (score 11):

Tommy's answer mentioned it just "en passant":

*You could buy one of Atari’s laser printers plus the ST, and DTP software for quite a bit less than Apple’s LaserWriter alone.*

but that was indeed one innovation that was brought by the Atari: bare laser printer without own rendering controller, using the computer to replace it. A technique that came much, much later in the Windows world with the so called "GDI Lasere Technology".

This allowed to sell the laser printer for significantly less than the competition.

================

Atari also pioneered CD-ROM with the CDAR-504, earlier than most other. It flopped, because the market was not ready yet, but it is one of the first to have.

Comment: And a technique that, while it made some sense at the time, has been a horrible thing ever since. Once I had a customer, thinking they were saving me trouble, buy a laser printer and connect it themselves to replace another one. It didn't work. Why? They didn't ask me and saved (literally) < $ 20 by buying the cheaper model with GDI-only. The more expensive (but not by much) had full PCL *necessary for their shared medical records and billing systems*. Had to replace it - waste of my time and their money.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: The idea makes even more sense today as it did back then. The key insight is that it's cheaper to get a 25% faster CPU than it is to add a similar processing capacity to an external device in the form of an independent microcontroller, and that faster CPU is also useful for other tasks. Saving $20 is indeed not worth it, that sounds like two models which shared the same hardware and merely had a marketing difference.

Comment: @MSalters The devices, and I still see this today, likely had some minor differences beyond just pure marketing. In the olden days, that better CPU, RAM, etc. was quite a bit. But today (and already 15 - 20 or so years ago when I had this particular incident, can't find exactly when it was right now) the incremental cost is *tiny*. Similar to the difference between a scan/print/copy machine and a fax/scan/print/copy machine (which needs a modem and phone jack added but uses the same CPU/etc.). The difference for GDI vs. PCL is possibly just extra RAM + different firmware.

Comment: Not to mention that the laser printer was a very long horror story to early adopters. THe software was buggy as hell, crashed the system without any reason at random times. A friend who used Ataris for all his office employees (way into the 90s and otherwise quite happy) had to buy a separate system just acting as printer controller, spooling from diskettes.

Comment: @MSalters In fact, next to all printers are used that way today. They simply get a bitmap to print, Font rendering is done on the PC anyway. Or when was the last time you had to look for a printer font?

Answer (score 4):

The sad thing for me is that the ST's blitter chip didn't make it in time to be included on mass production as part of the base spec.

I was fortunate to visit Atari during the early ST years and saw the blitter chip running on a prototype system.

If they had included it from the start it would have been a very capable system at a price point that was unbeatable.

Answer (score 3):

The perception of 'new' is maybe an individual one as...

> Recalling the rise of 16bit era, defined mainly by Motorola 68k cpu computers

When ignoring the TI 99/4 (and PC (*1)) that is.

> The Mac, brought the GUI interface.

Not really. It was already on sale since 1981 by [Xerox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Star) (and others) (*2) as well as offered in form of the Apple Lisa, which wasn't so much more expensive as the mac. Consider that, at the time when the Mac came with a single drive and 128 KiB at 2500 USD, the Lisa 2/5 was sold with four times the memory (wich was pricey at the time), larger screen and 5 MiB hard disk for 5000 USD - dropping even further with the MacXL.

> The A bomb,

The what?

> the Amiga, with its custom chips-coprocessors,

Which is essentially just a souped (*3) up Atari 800 chipset (*4), so nothing basically new here (*5).

> colourful graphics,

See Atari 800.

> stereo sound,

See Apple II sound cards, like the [Mockingboard A of 1983](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw74ayuLp5o) (*6).

> pre-emptive multitasking OS

Many computers had that already decades before, not to mention MP/M for standard S100 boxes. Oh, and for the home computer segment for sure the Sinclair QL, did beat the Amiga not only by time but in quality as well (*7).

Having that out of the way, the Amiga OS did in fact set a true first by being the first **Multimedia** OS outside research (*8). Amiga OS did not only allow to play multimedia, but moved it from a special (application) mode into a generic feature with seamless integration, and right into mainstream. A feature others, like Windows, BeOS or MacOS, only gained more than a decade later.

That's a first that'll stand the test of time.

> and probably other stuff which I forget.

I'd have a hard time to come up with any other.

> And also Atari ST. Well, it had midi ports embedded, making it successful among musicians. I also remember its crisp 70Hz 640x400 monochrome monitor, very easy for the eyes, paired with a nice, legible 8x16 font. But did it bring any novelty, like the aformentioned two (Amiga, Mac)?

Now, if you consider any of the above parts (GUI, Graphics) as new, then the Atari's screen mode was for sure revolutionary. While such screens were known with professional system, it was a first on the "affordable" price segment.

**I'd say, the 'new' in the all examples mentioned is the affordable part. Scaling existing features to enable a mass market.**

> PS: I also remember IBM PC with its 8/16bit 8088 cpu as a lousy machine with only one nice feature: Its expansion slots!

A feature IBM copied from the Apple II - which can be considered in many details the blueprint for big blue's PC :))

---

*1 - Yes, the 8088 is for all context a 16 bit system. Bus width is about the least significant factor, or would you consider a 68030 working on an 8 bit bus (which it can without additional logic by simply tying DTACK0/1) an 8 bit CPU? The 8088 is a smart choice, as it's only 25-30% slower than a 8086 at the same speed, but saving on components.

*2 - Sold in considerable numbers as 8010 since 1981, as well as several thousand by Siemens as EMS 5800 since 1982. Heck, there is even one to be see [within Commodore's Amiga department](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf2Jv2VfIqE&feature=youtu.be&t=842)- the large screen in the corner.

*3 - After all it was designed by the same team as the preceding Atari chipset - and intended to become an Atari machine.

*4 - [ANTIC, C/GTIA and POKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_8-bit_family#Design) became [Angus, Denise and Paula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Chip_Set#Overview_of_chips), maintaining essentially the same organisation of

- DMA/Address Ggeneration (ANTIC/Agnus)
- Video generation (GTIA/Denise)
- Audio/Joysticks/Serial and other I/O (POKEY/Paula)

*5 - In fact, there were tricks the Atari Chipset could do (at lower resloution), impossible for the Amiga - like anything charset related.

*6 - The board used/shown is a 1:1 modern replica. only difference is a standard stereo connector.

*7 - Using multitasking on the Amiga was comparable clumsy and error prone, while the QL could do it with a few lines in BASIC.

*8 -That is outside specific applications, supported by add on hardware. All the elements from DMA for video generation all the way to Genlock have been made as early as the first [bitmap video cards for micros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromemco_Dazzler).

Comment: Were any Apple II stereo sound cards released before the ST?

Comment: You're right about TI 99/4; but IBM PC was 8/16 bit, 8088, not full 16bit (8086). GUI is Xerox's innovation indeed, but it never got out of Xerox essentially, they didn't believe in their own innovation! Apple Lisa had limited acceptance, so I consider GUI to reach the masses through Mac. Regarding Amiga, I really can't think of any such mouth-watering machine at that time. Probably parts were found in other systems, but as a whole (graphics, sound, OS) there was nothing like it I believe. It took years to reach it.

Comment: @snips-n-snails I think they pretty much all were, including the one that people are remember likely to remember, the Mockingboard from 1983. Wikipedia places the ALF MC16 as the first Apple II sound card, launched in 1978.

Comment: @Krackout I tend to think the 8088 is a relatively smart choice given IBM's intention to launch in 1981 — it was at that point probably the only processor with an 8-bit bus to keep costs competitive and an obvious upgrade path (i.e. the 8086) in case of success.

Comment: @snips-n-snails The Mockingboard A of 1983 featured two sound chips one for each side. It could as well hold two speech chips. See this video of an almost perfect [Mockingboard replica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw74ayuLp5o) prior mockingboards could be patched for stereo. Also, tehre was always the chance to plug in two cards.

Comment: @Krackout don't get me going on bus size. It's most definitly the least criteria for CPU classification. or would you consider a 68020 working on an 8 bit bus (which it can without additional logic) an 8 bit CPU? The 8088 is a smart choice, as it's only 25-30% slower than a 8086 at the same speed, saving on components. I did consider the Amiga back then an uggly clutch and toy computer not really good for anything. A somewhat improved Atari 800. It was slower than an Atari ST, an the OS was sub par compared to any other - but that's my memory, being the hardware geek I am, YMMV.

Comment: Oh, and @Krackout don't tell my 1982 self that the Siemens EMS 5800 it worked on didn't exist. :)  Xerox sold the [Star Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Star) starting in 1981 (two years before the Lisa), and Siemens OEMed it about the same time. Several thousand have been sold in Germany alone. I still think fondly about the UI.

Comment: Concerning Note 6, I disagree.  Multitasking on the Amiga was very popular and robust, because of 2 reasons.  1) **ARexx** made communication among multiple processes extremely simple, compared to the raw IPC ports of the vanilla Amiga OS.  I honestly cannot say how that would compare to QL Basic, though.  2) Vendors strove, and largely succeeded, in making their applications robust and friendly in a multiprocess environment.  The Amiga users and press and even other vendors forced their hand.  HW protection would have been nice, but lacking that, talented developers did very well.

Comment: @RichF I got to admit, I only experienced it 'raw' which was much but not fun. And it was quite frugal. Popularity isn't an argument in favour - the C64 was popular as well :) HW Protection isn't a must, I can live quite witout..

Comment: @Raffzahn I did not mean popular in the sense of sales, but ubiquity.  Virtually every major non-game Amigo application adopted Arexx as its script language and documented the external access to its functional via English language ARexx commands implemented via ports.. ARexx became so popular, Commodore eventually made it a native part of the AmigaDOS.  My main point is that QL Basic might have been very good, but so was ARexx.

Comment: Xerox invented some of the key _components_ of a GUI; Windows, icons, highlighting, mouse & pointer, etc. But, I think it was Apple that first built a consistent framework around those things that we would recognize today. I never used a Xerox Star, but I used Xerox Altos and I used one of the Xerox Interlisp machines (Dandelion maybe?) and ISTR, the GUI on those machines was crude compared to what we saw on the first Macintoshes. (The Xerox screens sure where a whole lot bigger tho!)

Comment: Calling the TI99/4A a 16 bit computer is a bit of a stretch. It had a 16 bit CPU (and 256 bytes of RAM, which could be only considered like a kind of 6502 zero page) but the machine was through and through 8 bit.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well, in my memory is was two steps back from the Star system to the Lisa or Macintosh. The Star already had everything we know today - plus a better Keyboard with keys for copy/move/insert/properties, so no CTRL-C/-X/-V. It had much in common with later OS/2 and NextStep. The Mac felt like a step backward, needing way more complicated moves to do the same job. Personally I'd say it was a typical Jobs issue of trying to make things simpler than they need to be, resulting in more work.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter So, were's the difference to the IBM-PC? A 16 Bit CPU, but everything external only 8 bit.

Comment: @Raffzahn, OK. I'll buy that. Like I said, I never got my hands on a Star--just the Alto and the D-machines.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The Alto is like two generations before. But Star isn't so much a machine, as it is the Software package. Maybe take a [read here](https://guidebookgallery.org/articles/thexeroxstararetrospective). The hardware below were at first the D-Machines, later i386 based. At that time it was renamed to ViewPoint and later again renamed to GlobalView - this time even doing colour. But D-Machines were available independant form the Star software, mostly fitted with a LISP system and AFAIK also for Modula. So it's quite likely that you dint get to see the office system.

Comment: "essentially just a souped up Atari 800 chipset", "was designed by the same team", "tricks the Atari Chipset could do, impossible for the Amiga" -- this all feels like a downplaying of the amiga chipset, with hardly any technical facts presented.

Comment: @Raffzahn the difference is that the 16 bitness of 8088 brought a plus that 8 bit machines could not. The extended memory, even if on a 8 bit bus went beyond 64K. No such thing in the TI-99/4. The TMS-9900 had 16 bit register (all 3).
So it is technically 16 bit, but it was crippled to worse than 8 bit. The thing is, using the TMS9900 was a stopgap because their 8 bit version of the chip didn't pan out.

Comment: Yeah, comparing the Amiga chipset to the Atari 800 is ill-conceived and lazy writing.  Prove it or remove it.

Comment: @lvd Beside that the Amiga chipset was done by Jay Miner (et. al.) who as well did the VCS' TIA and ANTIC/GTIA that made up the Atari 800? The Amiga is his vision of evolving further.There is a clear heritage - like Copper display list, multiple modes per screen and indefinite height sprites. What got lost are for example are functionalities related to character bitmap modes.  There is no downplay, if at all, I'm guilty of not hyping the Amiga beyond what it was. All history - including the fact, that the Amiga was intended to be the next generation Atari - read it up.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica As I see it would be rather up to you to prove otherwise. It may be a quite interesting how you want to nullify what its creators themself have told. Until then, simply read any Amiga related history.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter The way the 99/4 was designed doesn't change the fact that it's a 16 bit CPU. It's the [single chip implementation of the 16 bit TI 990 series mini computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS9900). What you talk about are addressing features. The standard way to handle memory past 64 KiB for 990(0) systems was the SN74LS610/1/2/3 memory mapper, extending the address range it to 24 bit by using 4 KiB pages. There was simply no reason for the 99/4 to have this - especially not as it was intended to use the 9985 controller (a 9940 variant) instead.

Comment: @Raffzahn You’re the one making the claim, and you know perfectly well it’s a bold one.  You know that requires bold proofs.  This trollish response only lives up to my expectations.

Comment: In the world I grew up in the Amiga when it first appeared had a wow factor the likes of which I didn't see again until Doom came out. The ST had a slightly dimmer version of the same wow factor, except to musicians with MIDI stuff. The Mac also had a dimmer wow factor but in a kind of serious/businessy way. In this part of the world the 8-bit Ataris had no wow factor at all, they were maybe also-rans in the Apple II world. All independent of who designed the hardware how. More technical people in other countries surely had different experiences at the time.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm not making any claim, just citing well known facts. So far, if at all, it's you trolling history by denying it without any proof. The Amiga did not appear out of nowhere. The development line VCS/Atari 800/Amiga is a well known one, each with incremental features over the previous. Maybe listen to [Joe Decuir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy_8LV38nLY), the man behind the graphics and the chips, how they developed the Amiga out of their previous work at Atari. Or read his [detailed description](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7575776).

Comment: @hippietrail I'd recommend spending some time looking at the 800 and how they interact with via DMA. Joe Decuir did a [overview talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlVpu_QSHyw), with focus on the Atari at VCF. The slides can be [found here](http://vcfed.org/vcfpnw/2019/presentations/Joe%20Decuir%20-%20VCF19%20R3.pdf). Video wise they were fast superiour to like a C64 - which later showed. The Mac never was a great wow to me, as I was already familiar with Xerox. (never cite me, I will deny, but...) The Apple II had it's wow for being early and hackable. Beside that it was outclassed soon.

Comment: The Mac didn't quite wow me either. I was impressed with the font & text & illustration stuff, even the dithering, but I could see that others were wowed at shops and computer shows. Even the flying toasters seemed to blow the minds of the day.

Comment: 2) Are you sure that's a Xerox? Looks more like a Sun 2/3 workstation to me, which Commodore used a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> The A bomb, the Amiga, with its custom chips-coprocessors, colourful
> graphics, stereo sound, pre-emptive multitasking OS and probably other
> stuff which I forget.

I've never heard Amiga being called the "A bomb", especially as both the Atari and Mac would display bombs as error messages with Atari even showing mushroom clouds in the very early version of TOS ;-) The Amiga with her Guru Meditation is probably the last computer that should be called "A bomb"...

Colourful graphics and stereo sound are not an innovation, both are just an evolution of previous computers. The flexibility of the graphic and sound system was a strength, although the first was present in Jay Miner's previous work, the Atari 8-bit computers. The Amiga also wasn't the first computer with a preemptive multitasking os.

> And also Atari ST. Well, it had midi ports embedded, making it
> successful among musicians. I also remember its crisp 70Hz 640x400
> monochrome monitor, very easy on the eyes, paired with a nice, legible
> 8x16 font. But did it bring any novelty, like the aforementioned two
> (Amiga, Mac)?

Both MIDI ports and the mono display were innovative and were seen as such in the 80's. There were external MIDI interfaces for other computers but including them as standard and having a flicker free display created a whole MIDI ecosystem. MIDI was also used for the 16 player deathmatch first person shooter MIDI Maze.

I don't think it's helpful to always ask which computer "did it first". Neither of the 68k machines appeared out of thin air. Bringing certain features to the masses (multitasking, midi etc.) is a novelty in itself.

Comment: What was considered innovative about the mono display? Seemed quite unremarkable to me

Comment: @OmarL It was quite hi-res for a home computer of the day. I bought my Atari 1040ST with monitor for £800 I believe. This represented good value for what it was at the time in 1986.